# Bool(false) Result when Parsing Float to Date in PHP from Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have to change format date from my excel to upload in db. In excel, that row already in date format.

When i'm debug that row, the result of date is float(43772). Then, i try to change format using **date_create_from_format**. But now, the result of date always **bool(false)** or error : **date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given**. My code like this:

```
$column = 'A';
$row = 2;

while ($objexcel->getCell('A' . $row)->getValue() != '' && $objexcel 
>getCell('B' . $row)->getValue() != '') {

$tgl = $objexcel->getCell('D' . $row)->getValue();
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $tgl);   /* here problem */
$update = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');   /* here problem */

}
```

Can you help me how to fix this problem?

Comment: What is the value of your `$tgl`?

Comment: in excel it's d/m/Y(eg: 07/2/2019) but when i'm debug it the value is float(43772)

Comment: So the problem isn't about date function, the problem is getting your row value from excel. Which library are you using to parse excel?

Comment: i'm just using PHPExcel, is that any solution?

Answer (score 0):

That date value isn't a unix timestamp; it's an MS Excel serialized timestamp... you can use `getFormattedValue()` instead of `getValue()` to read it as a formatted string (assuming that you read the file with readDataOnly set to false; or you can use the `ExcelToPHP()` and `ExcelToPHPObject()` methods available in the `PHPExcel_Shared_Date` class to convert it to a unix timestamp, or a DateTime object